# I am using Google Cloud Messaging for push notifications in my app and i have 2 basic doubts about it

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

1. Is GCM the only way for push notifications in android? And is it advisable over other methods (if there are any)?
2. So let's say my app from a device registers on GCM. Is it the app itself which is assosciated with the device that registers itself, or the user and his email id that register? If my user switches devices in future, will the same 'registration token' work for him ? Or in a similar scenario if a user with another g-mail id registers to my app from the same device, do i push notifications to the same device with 2 different registration tokens?
3. Extending to what i asked in 2, suppose a single user has his g-mail id working on my app on different devices. Does GCM push the notification to all those devices, or only one of them? And if one, then how does it prioritize?

Comment: 1) no others exists, GCM is not real time 2) GCM id is tied to installation 3) you need to send to all devices owned by the same user, they are not prioritized that I know of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, there are other push notification services in Android, like [Parse](http://www.parse.com). However, it is **strongly recommended** to use the default push notification service that is present in any Android device that has Google Play Store, because that reduces battery usage. If you are pushing your app *somewhere else* though, like Amazon Store, keep in mind that Kindle Fire does not comply with this and doesn't have Google Play Services -- at least as far as I know.
2. The registration token is **very volatile** and is not bound at all to an email. Actually, sometimes the same device may get a new GCM ID out of the blue. There are many tutorials on GCM's best practices, but [Google's](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) is the best way to start. What you **should** do to prevent problems is store the GCM id of your device in your database, so you can always know which ID is currently associated to your device. GCM may give you new IDs for no reason, so always parse its response properly and store the new ID it may provide, linking it to the device.
3. GCM doesn't really care which Google account is your app using. That means you can register as many devices as you want with the same account. You have to manage to which devices you push notifications, because the ID is managed by device.

**Be careful:** there's been some changes with the API lately, so a lot of unnoficial tutorials you find on the internet may point to deprecated methods.

Comment: Out of curiosity, who is **strongly recommending** to use GCM over other services?

Comment: **Google**, mostly. They do have a point in doing that, because having many different services running in background to manage incoming notifications is battery-intensive, so it's good for the OS to have as little as possible. It's not up to us discuss whether GCM is better than the others and I only have practical experience with GCM, but I find it overly complicated. For example, when registering a new device, most of the times the request will fail. The docs say: keep retrying and implement exponential backoff -- that's short for 'we don't support all the requests that we receive'.

Answer (score 2):

1. There are other ways of sending notifications, Tokodu and RabbitMQ for example. I wont go over if X is better than Y, since it's not allowed on StackOverflow.
2. A unique device token is generated for the device, how you use this device token is totally up to you. You can make it unique for the user by, for example, implementing a login system, so that the device token is created and stored in a database (together with the user information). Let's say if two different users uses your application on a shared device, they can both receive notifications on the same device if you allow them to. It depends on your own implementation.
3. This again depends on how you chose to implement the GCM features on your client and server side. For example, you can choose to store device tokens for each and every device the user has installed the app on, or you can store the latest device token so that notifications are only sent to one of the user's devices.

I hope this helps clear some things up.

Answer (score 2):

Besides good answers above, if you need a push notification solution for a working environment **without Internet access**, I suggest **SignalR** of Microsoft, which has already supported Android and Java (you can find out more at [GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client)).

Hope this helps little!